# A Windows script to merge three csv file columns into one single column

Tags: csv, excel, vbscript, batch-file, vba

I can do this within excel for example using the =CONCATENATE function to merge a number of columns into one single column. But i want to do is merge columns within 3 different csv files within the same folder into one single column. I want to run this via batch script so something like a VBScript the CMD copy command does not seem to work.

Here is the file structure:

**File1.csv**

- Column1:  www.domain.com/
- Column2:  www.nwdomain.com/
- Column3:  www.stackdomain.com/
- Column4:  www.example-domain.com/

**File2.csv**

- Column1:  about
- Column2:  contact
- Column3:  index
- Column4:  faq

**File3.csv**

- Column1: .html
- Column2: .html
- Column3: .html
- Column4: .html

**Result in output file:**

- Column1:  www.domain.com/about.html
- Column2:  www.nwdomain.com/contact.html
- Column3:  www.stackdomain.com/index.html
- Column4:  www.example-domain.com/faq.html

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
::
(
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a IN ('findstr /n /r "." ^<csv1.csv') DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%c IN ('findstr /n /r "." ^<csv2.csv') DO ( 
  IF %%a==%%c FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%e IN ('findstr /n /r "." ^<csv3.csv') DO (
   IF %%a==%%e (
    FOR /f "tokens=1-4delims=," %%m IN ("%%b") DO (
     FOR /f "tokens=1-4delims=," %%r IN ("%%d") DO (
      FOR /f "tokens=1-4delims=," %%w IN ("%%f") DO (
       ECHO.%%m%%r%%w,%%n%%s%%x,%%o%%t%%y,%%p%%u%%z
      )
     )
    )
   )   
  )
 )
)
)>new.csv
```

should work.

What it does is,

1. For file1, FINDSTR "outputs" any line which contains any character (`/r "."`) preceded by the line number and a colon (`/n`). This "output" is read by the `FOR /f` and parsed into 2 tokens, delimited by the colon (`tokens=1*` means 'the first token;all of the rest of the line') and the effect is to put the line number in `%%a` and the rest of the line, which is the line from the original `.csv` into `%%b`
2. FOR EACH LINE of `csv1`Repeat for `csv2`, this time placing the line number in `%%c`, line in `%%d`
3. Only if the line numbers match, repeat for `csv3` with the number in `%%e` and text in `%%f`
4. If the line number from this last file matches, parse the line text in each of `%%b`, `%%d` and `%%f` - this time selecting the four columns, separated by commas. This data appears in `%%m`..`%%p`, `%%r`..`%%u`, `%%w`..`%%z` All we have to do then is butt-up the appropriate parts and insert the commas.

DONE!

---

Source and test results, including run time (5 rows)

```
start:21:45:40.87
end  :21:45:41.09

csv1.csv =========
www.domain.com/,www.nwdomain.com/,www.stackdomain.com/,www.example-domain.com/
www.domain.com/,www.nwdomain.com/,www.stackdomain.com/,www.example-domain.com/
www.domain.com/,www.nwdomain.com/,www.stackdomain.com/,www.example-domain.com/
www.domain.com/,www.nwdomain.com/,www.stackdomain.com/,www.example-domain.com/
www.domain.com/,www.nwdomain.com/,www.stackdomain.com/,www.example-domain.com/
csv2.csv =========
about,contact,index,faq
about,contact,index,faq
about,contact,index,faq
about,contact,index,faq
about,contact,index,faq
csv3.csv =========
.html,.html,.html,.html
.html,.html,.html,.html
.html,.html,.html,.html
.html,.html,.html,.html
.html,.html,.html,.html
new.csv =========
www.domain.com/about.html,www.nwdomain.com/contact.html,www.stackdomain.com/index.html,www.example-domain.com/faq.html
www.domain.com/about.html,www.nwdomain.com/contact.html,www.stackdomain.com/index.html,www.example-domain.com/faq.html
www.domain.com/about.html,www.nwdomain.com/contact.html,www.stackdomain.com/index.html,www.example-domain.com/faq.html
www.domain.com/about.html,www.nwdomain.com/contact.html,www.stackdomain.com/index.html,www.example-domain.com/faq.html
www.domain.com/about.html,www.nwdomain.com/contact.html,www.stackdomain.com/index.html,www.example-domain.com/faq.html
=============
```

Comment: This seems to be very slow on 5 string matches.

Comment: If you mean that you have only 5 rows of data, then I've posted my test data and run results. I made a minor edit (on the `ECHO.%%m%%r...` line there were 4 `%` before the `w` - this should be **2** [put a spurious `%` into the output]) but that would have no effect on timing. Are you only using 5 rows of data? If so, could you post them (or an edited version). Obviously, don't post hundreds of lines... As you see, my run-time was 0.22 seconds, which I wouldn't describe as particularly slow. OTOH, I have had `CMD` decide to unaccountably take a long time and require a new CMD instance.

Answer (score 1):

In VBScript:

```
Const delim = ","

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set f1 = fso.OpenTextFile("File1.csv")
Set f2 = fso.OpenTextFile("File2.csv")
Set f3 = fso.OpenTextFile("File3.csv")

Do Until f1.AtEndOfStream Or f2.AtEndOfStream Or f3.AtEndOfStream
  a1 = Split(f1.ReadLine, delim)
  a2 = Split(f2.ReadLine, delim)
  a3 = Split(f3.ReadLine, delim)

  n = Min(UBound(a1), UBound(a2), UBound(a3))
  Dim aout(n)

  For i = 0 To n
    aout(i) = a1(i) & a2(i) & a3(i)
  Next

  WScript.StdOut.WriteLine Join(aout, delim)
Loop

f1.Close
f2.Close
f3.Close

Function Min(a, b, c)
  If a<=b Then
    If c<a Then
      Min = c
    Else
      Min = a
    End If
  Else
    If c<b Then
      Min = c
    Else
      Min = b
    End If
  End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Although not really programming, a quick and dirty way is to open all files in Excel, create a new `XLS` or `XLSX` file, then use this formula in the first cell of the newly created file:

```
=[File1.csv]File1!A1&[File2.csv]File2!A1&[File3.csv]File3!A1
```

where `File1.csv`, `File2.csv`, and `File3.csv` are your CSV files.
Then drag across the columns / rows to apply the formula.